# Updating BelongsTo Relationships in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

everyone,
i have table **statuses** with fields `id`, `user_id`, `parent_id`, `body`. 
now the status table has relations with user like this :

**Status Model**

```
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function scopeNotReply($query) {
        return $query->whereNull('parent_id');
    }

    public function replies() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Status', 'parent_id');
    }
```

**User Model**

```
public function statuses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Status', 'user_id');
}
```

but, unfortunately i can't access the `user_id` when i want to reply the status and save into database with same table `statuses`. I use the `associate` method and the StatusController is like this :

```
public function postReply(Request $request, $statusId){
    $this->validate($request, [
        "reply-{$statusId}" => 'required|max:1000',
    ]);

    $status = Status::notReply()->find($statusId)->first();

    $reply = Status::create([
        'body'  => $request->input("reply-{$statusId}"),
    ])->user()->associate(Auth::user());

    $status->replies()->save($reply);

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

everytime i try to reply the status, i got this error message `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value`.

> Could anybody to help me to solve this problem ??

**Thank You**

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because you're creating the `Status` before the `user_id` has been associated with it.

One way to get around this would be to move the `user_id` logic inside the create array i.e.:

```
Status::create([
    'body'    => $request->input("reply-{$statusId}"),
    'user_id' => Auth:user()->id
]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer but i still getting same error message.